# trading interview question: Find the probability of two line segment intersecting with each other.

Tags: probability

Find the probability of two line segment intersecting with each other. The end points of lines are informally sampled from an uniform distribution between 0 and 1.
There are similar problems in this site however, i don't see any posts address the end points of lines are drawn from uniform distribution.

Here's my attempt, since the only case the intersection won't happen is if they were parallel. Say They are 8 numbers that we need to draw from the distribution. the first 4 numbers (2 points) are basically free, and we can have another point anywhere also, but the remaining one point has to be the "chosen one" for the two lines to be parallel, so I have $$1 -\frac{(2)}{(n)}$$ This is correct?

Comment: what is (2) and (n)?

Comment: n is the total number from the uniform distribution, 2 is the two numbers that i need to form the 4th point

Comment: "...since the only case the intersection won't happen is if they were parallel." This is not correct, since the problem asks about line segments, not lines. I think the problem is asking whether two random intervals inside of [0,1] overlap. It might be easier to calculate this probability if you first sample 4 points from the interval, and then assign them randomly to the two line segments, although I haven't checked that this gives an identical distribution over pairs of intervals.

Comment: The probability is most likely less than 1/3, and definitely less than 2/3. Given any 4 end points, there are 3 pairs of line segments. Only if all 4 are on a line do 2 pairs intersect. If the convex hull is a quadrilateral, then 1 pair intersect. Else, 0 pairs intersect.

Comment: I misunderstood. Because OP said 8 numbers and parallel lines, I thought they were finding x and y coordinates on a 2-d plane. It seems like this is a 1-d question, in which case the answer is 2/3 ( i.e. The if all 4 are on a line case I mentioned )

Comment: @CalvinLin I didn't really understand the interview question to be honest, can you please explain what do you mean by 1-d question. Thanks.

Comment: You pick four numbers, $a,b,c,d$ uniformly in $[0,1]$.  The question is what is the chance the line segments $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ overlap.  If we rename the intervals so $a$ is the smallest number, the segments will overlap unless $b$ is less than both $c$ and $d$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability is $\frac 23$.  There are four points drawn from the interval and all that matters is which point is paired with the lowest of the four.  If it is the second lowest, the line segments will not intersect.  If it is either of the other two, the line segments will intersect.

Comment: I didn't really understand the interview question to be honest, can you please elaborate on how you draw the 4 points (8 numbers ?) do we not care about the length of the line segment ?

Comment: @szd116 You don't need eight numbers, only four numbers. All four points are on the same line between points labeled "0" and "1". So you choose the two numbers $a,b$ as the endpoints of one segment and $c,d$ as the endpoints of the other segment, and then if it turns out (for example) that $a < b<c<d$ the segments don't intersect, but if (for example) $b < c < a < d$ then they intersect.

Comment: Interestingly, a uniform distribution is not required, merely a continuous one.

Comment: @DavidK ahh i see, it's not all that difficult once i figured out what the question means. Thanks.